# Google API for voice assistant in web application

Tags: google-voice-search

we are basically looking for voice to voice support in Google API. Currently using Alexa to serve the purpose but we like to use google API that should get question in voice format and respond back with answer in voice format.Please give us a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is google cloud speech api which is still in beta. https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Still not recommended for production needs to implement our own logic for smooth navigation.

Alternative https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html which only works with chrome